# How to access an object from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following list of objects:

```
Object {7: Object, 22: Object, 32: Object, 102: Object, 104: Object, 105: Object, 106: Object, 117: Object, 118: Object, 119: Object}
```

I tried to access the first object like this but it didn't work:

```
this.props.sites[0]
```

What is wrong, how can I make it work?

Comment: Keys shouldn't be integers :(

Comment: You don't have an item with the key `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sites[0]` takes the first element of `sites` if `sites` **is an array**. In your case its a JavaScript object, which has its element indexed as key-value pairs.

To get the first element (which has the key `7`), you can get it like below:

```
this.props.sites[7];
```

Working example:

```js
function test() {
  this.props = {
    sites: {
      1: 'x',
      7: 'y',
      10: 'z'
    }
  };
  
  console.log(this.props.sites[1], this.props.sites[7], this.props.sites[10]);

}

test();
```

Comment: I think this.props.sites["7"] is correct. this.props.sites[7] => undefined.

Comment: @MarkoSavic -- Please see the snippet. Number keys are fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ObjectTest = {
    7: object,
    22: object
}
render(){
 return (
     <div>
        Object.keys(ObjectTest).map( (key)=> {
          return <div>
            {ObjectTest[key][YOU MUST HAVE ELEMENT IN YOUR OBJECT]}
          </div>
        })
     </div>
 )
}
```